# How to move ASP.NET 2.0 applications to the cloud

Tags: asp.net, cloud, saas, migrate, multi-tenant

How can we move our existing ASP .Net 2.0 application to the cloud platform ? 
What all changes are required in existing application at code level as well as database level ?

**Update:** I have one ASP.Net 2.0 application with SQL 2008 database. I want to deploy it on the cloud environment with multi-tenancy support. 
In that case what changes are required. Currently 'ConnectionString' is configured in web.config file. How to change the code/ database to achieve multitenancy support.

Basically I am looking for steps to move existing ASP.Net application to the cloud platform.

Please suggest resources for the same.

Comment: The question in its current form does not make sense. What are your requirements when moving to the cloud. Do you need the clouds' elastic infinite scale or you are just planning to use the infrastructure. In the first case you may need to change a lot of things (completely rework the database to work with cloud storage, get rid of sessions, etc.) in the other case you don't need to change anything - just deploy to a VM.

Comment: @Stilgar - Please find my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by multitenancy suppport. Multitenancy usually means that you will need to work on your application and segregate the data for different organizations. Not sure what the cloud has to do with this. If you are expecting to just spin different instances for different organizations you will have to do work again with the API of the cloud provider in question. Some of them can manage applications and instances automatically.

Cloud provides scalability and elasticity (automatic scalability) it does not provide mutltitenancy by itself. To achieve maximum scalability you may need to use cloud data store (usually key/value) and let go of relational databases. This may require serious rearchitecturing of the application. Whether you need this scalability and elasticity is another topic and you may just use the cloud as infrastructure (i.e. they will manage the servers for you)

Comment: Ok lets consider a simple case. I have created a simple ASP.Net application with login and register pages. Currently there is one database and a table inside it. Now, if I want to give multitenancy support for this particular case, how to go with it. If I have 3 users with 3 organizations, I want to make use of same application instance and same database, what all changes are required in my current code.

Comment: You need to add a key to most of your tables that says to which organization the data belongs. Then when you do your queries you add a WHERE clause to filter the result based on the organization ID. I don't think this relates to the cloud in any way.